# How to execute an async function multiple times in sequence until the first success

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a function

```
def request(url: String): Future[String]
```

and need to write a function

```
def requestFirst(urls: List[String]): Future[String]
```

that calls request(url) in sequence untill it completes successfully (in this case the successful value is returned)  or requests for all urls fail (in this case all failures are returned).

How can this be done in Scala?

Comment: Could you please describe bit more what you want to achieve?
If you need to wait for result, It's not Future any more.
And usually in the case a method have a chance to produce an error, `Either/Option` would be used. plus, I don't get why return type would be `Future[String]` instead of `Seq[Future[String]]`

Comment: I need the first successful result, not all the results. I have multiple servers and only one of them is active at any given moment in time. Inactive servers reply with error. I need to return a future because I need to pass it down to complete{... } from akka-http.

Comment: I'm not sure how tied you are to those function definitions but `Future.find(...)` might be worth a look. This would allow you to do something like `Future.find(urls.map(u => Future(u)))(isSuccessfulRequest)` where `isSuccessfulRequest` would evaluate to true if the request was successful.

Answer (score 2):

```
def requestFirst(urls: List[String]): Future[String] = {
  val default: Future[String] = Future.failed(new scala.Exception("all failed"))
  urls.foldLeft(default)((prevFuture, currentUrl) => {
    prevFuture fallbackTo (request(currentUrl))
  })
}
```

OR

```
def requestFirst(urls: List[String]): Future[String] = {
  def requestFirstInternal(urlSubset: List[String]): Future[String] = {
    if(urlSubset.isEmpty) {
      Future.failed(new Exception("Exhausted all urlSubset"))
    } else {
      request(urlSubset.head) fallbackTo {
        requestFirstInternal(urlSubset.tail)
      }
    }
  }
  requestFirstInternal(urls)
}
```

Comment: Probably, Its better to get head/tail of the list instead of doing magic with indices

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I used recoverWith instead of fallbackTo to collect errors. Also your solution returns the first error in case if all requests failed (not exhausted error).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with based on @parnav-shukla answer:

```
def requestFirst(urls: List[String]): Future[String] = {
  def requestFirstInternal(urlSubset: List[String], errors: Seq[String]): Future[String] = {
    if(urlSubset.isEmpty) {
      Future.failed(new Exception(errors.mkString("\n")))
    } else {
      request(urlSubset.head) recoverWith { t =>
        requestFirstInternal(urlSubset.tail, errors ++ Seq(t.getMessage))
      }
    }
  }
  requestFirstInternal(urls, Seq.empty)
}
```